# How to Pass a JavaScript function that contains parameters as parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This seems not working:

```
<a href="#ThisSweetConversationYouOpened" ng-click="OpenChat(returnNotmyID(19,20))">
```

Please help

Thank you

**Edit:** 
I still didn't get a working answer yet. So found an alternative that is working.

```
<a href="#ThisSweetConversationYouOpened" ng-init="message.Interlocuter = returnNotmyID(19,20)" ng-click="OpenChat(message.Interlocuter)">
```

But still the question is open if anyone knows, please help

Comment: This should work. Are you sure 'returnNotmyID' is in the scope?

Comment: @eric_s That won't work. It will invoke the `OpenChat` function call immediately.

Comment: Did you tried my answer below?

Comment: @TSR, suggest you expand on your question.  Is your concern that you keep the result of `OpenChat(returnNotmyID(19,20))` for use elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You have to nest your function call into another function that takes no parameters.

```js
<a href="#ThisSweetConversationYouOpened" ng-click="function(){OpenChat(returnNotmyID(19,20))}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an anonimous function that call your function like this:

```
ng-click="OpenChat(function(){ returnNotmyID(19,20); })"
```

**NOTE:** you can play with arguments (if any) of the anonimous function as you like (you can pass them to `returnNotmyID` if you like too).

**EDIT:**

if you want to return the value of `returnNotmyID` use this:

```
ng-click="OpenChat(function(){ return returnNotmyID(19,20); })"
```

Comment: Not quite. This will invoke `OpenChat` immediately.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm still confused which function he want to pass?

Comment: @TSR maybe you want to return the value of `returnNotmyID`. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function name as string with the parameters to parent function which will call the child (or inner) function dynamically with the parameters.

```
<a href="#ThisSweetConversationYouOpened" ng-click="OpenChat('returnNotmyID', 19, 20)">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.OpenChat = function (name, var1, var2)
{
     //check if the provided function name is actually a function in $scope
     if(angular.isFunction($scope[name]))
           $scope[name](var1, var2);   //call the inner function
}

//inner function
$scope.returnNotmyID = function(a, b)
{
     alert("Called: "+ a + " - b: "+ b)
}
```

For reference, I have created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bitf09a013/U3pVM/29688/).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the function and parameters as a callback.  Very similar to Ali Baig's answer.

This can be useful tool to keep modularity, particularly in situations where you want to send controller logic to a directive for execution.

Link:

```
<a href="#ThisSweetConversationYouOpened" ng-click="OpenChat_ALTERNATIVE(returnNotmyID, 19, 20)">  Alternative </a>
```

Controller:

```
function SimleController($scope) {
    $scope.result = '';

    $scope.returnNotmyID = function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    };

    $scope.OpenChat_ALTERNATIVE = function(passedFunction, arg1, arg2) {
        $scope.result = passedFunction(arg1, arg2);
    };
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gmmo37j/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You just need define `OpenChat` and `returnNotmyID` as the normal angular function.

```
$scope.OpenChat = function(fn) {
    fn && fn();
}
$scope.returnNotmyID = function(a, b) {
    alert("a + b = " + (a+b));
}
```

Demo:
https://codeide.co/hHezFzaL

Is it ok?